# Increase Swapfile on operational system

Tags: swap, rhel7

new to this and I am trying to figure what will be the best way to go on about this. I have a system that I need to increase its swap file, I realized that the swap partition is not lvm so that is kind of out. However, my current swap partition is 8Gb but needs to be at 16GB.

```
#  swapon -s
Filename      Type    Size      Used     Priority
/swapfile     file    8191996   6341008  -1
```

I guess my issue is that it is a swap file and not a partition (at least is an issue for me :(...) I read online I can use dd to create a swapfile, but I'm not sure I understand how to actually increase the size or if I need to create a new partition.

/etc/fstab looks like this:

```
/swapfile        swap           swap    defaults        0 0
```

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can resize the swapfile to gain the desired effect.
But I would recommend adding another swapfile, with the same priority, so you will not need to swap out the GB's of swapped data.

```
# Create another swapfile, mind the filename!
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile2 bs=1M count=8192
# Make the new file a swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile2
# Enable it
sudo swapon /swapfile2
# Change its priority
sudo swapon /swapfile2 -p -1 # Or anything you want
```

Then add `/swapfile2       swap           swap    defaults        0 0` to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: This has the benefit of not being without swap over my solution.

Comment: Thanks! so is there any pros vs. cons for either deleting the existing swap and creating a new one? or to just add a second swap partition? like in your example. I've been asked by a support team to increase it, so Im not sure if by creating another one will actually suffice

Comment: Pro for deleting the existing swap:
- No need to edit system files, less risk

Con for deleting the existing swap:
- May take a performance hit (swapping out) or even system instabilities if the system doesn't have enough RAM

Pro for creating a new one:
- No need to swap out, impact on performance is minimal

Con for creating a new one:
- Failure of editing a system file will screw your system on reboot

Comment: ok, so I added a /swapfile2 swap but I see two issues. First one is that even though I put to have the same preiority as the other swap file (-1), it does not take it and shows a priority of -2

`# swapon -s
Filename                  Type  Size          Used          Priority
/swapfile                   file     8191996   6238112     -1
/swapfile2                 file     8188         0                 -2
`

Also, when I run the `free -h` it only shows that swap has the previous 7.8G and not 16 as it's supposed to be after adding /swapfile2

Comment: It won't take negative values as its priority after an experiment. and /swapfile2 has size of 8188K (as opposed to /swapfile's 8191996K). `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile2 bs=1M count=8192` should create a 8192M file.

Answer (score 0):

A swapfile is really just that, an actual file used as swap. There are a couple of ways to go about this, best is to probably delete it and create a new one.

```
# this disables ALL swap, you can target with swapoff /swapfile
sudo swapoff -a
# delete old swap file
sudo rm /swapfile
# create new swap file. dd takes /dev/zero which always returns.. 0 then it
# writes that data into the file under 'of'. So it is just a file full of 0s
# bs is blocksize and count is number of blocks, so bs=1M and count=16284 
# will create a 16284 MByte file. Adjust count to make a bigger file.
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=16384
# make file a swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
# enable swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
# you already have swapfile of the same name in fstab, so no need to edit it
```